# Interpreting cointegration test

Tags: interpretation, cointegration, eigenvalues

I am very new to interpreting cointegration tests and eigenvalues, so any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what about the test or output you need help interpreting?

Comment: Related: [Interpretation of results from Johansen's co-integration test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/184241/).